# Value not changed in parent class

Tags: java, class, while-loop, boolean

My main class is called `MainClass` and it has the following code in it:

```
Startup startup = new Startup();
while (!startup.isDoneWelcoming()){
    System.out.print("Waiting for welcoming to finish."+br);
    try{Thread.sleep(5000);}catch(Exception waitEx){System.out.print(waitEx+br);}
}
```

And the value it checks for is from *another* class called `Startup` which has this code:

```
private boolean doneWelcoming=false;

void openWelcomeScreen(){
//irrelevant code...

//a welcome screen is displayed and when "get started" button is pressed
//it opens a new window from the Tutorial class
WelcomeScreen welcomeScreen = new WelcomeScreen();
welcomeScreen.openWelcomeScreen();

//irrelevant code...
}

void setWelcomeStatus(){
    System.out.print("Boolean \"doneWelcoming\" is true."+br);
    doneWelcoming=true;
}

public boolean isDoneWelcoming(){
    System.out.print("Boolean \"doneWelcoming\" value returned as: "+doneWelcoming+br);
    return doneWelcoming;
}
```

The `WelcomeScreen` class `extends` from `Startup` and has this code that initiates the method `createTutorialWindow` inside the `Tutorial` class:

```
void createTutorialWindow(){
    //ActionListener detects when the button is pressed and it does this...
    Tutorial startTutorial = new Tutorial();
    startTutorial.createTutorialWindow();
}
```

The `setWelcomeStatus` method is called from another class called `Tutorial` which `extends` from `Startup`. There I have a button and when pressed it does this:

setWelcomeStatus();

My problem is that I see this in my console:

> Waiting for welcoming to finish.
>   Button clicked. Will return welcoming process as complete.
>   Boolean "doneWelcoming" is true.
>   Boolean "doneWelcoming" value returned as: false

Which means that `doneWelcoming`'s value **does** change but it doesn't get returned as `true` to the original class and so my loop never stops. What should I change to fix this?

**EDIT**: Added code for `WelcomeScreen` class in both `Startup` and the class itself.
**NOTE**: It is rather obvious that a lot of instances of classes are involved, so it get a little complicated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try adding `volatile` before the `private boolean` in the declaration of `doneWelcoming`. It seems like you have a concurrency issue.

Comment: Something smells fishy. Your first code bit creates a new Startup object, and yet you have another class which extends Startup, you change this second class's state and then expect your original Startup instance above to change state. That's not how Java inheritance works, and to me it looks like you're mis-using inheritance. @RealSkeptic: thoughts?

Comment: Please post a valid [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) as code-formatted text so we can see for ourselves just what you're doing and why it's not working.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I suspect I might be violating some inheritance rule with all those instances I have so you might be right and limiting them might be the proper way to solve the problem.

Comment: On an important side note, I would suggest that you scrap the code that you're asking about. What you've got is a busy while loop where you poll a variable continuously, something that is a "code smell" -- a bad design that can cause problems now and later. **Much** better is to use an observer design pattern -- a listener of some type -- that gets notified when the start up code is done. Again to give the best solution is going to require that you improve this question by posting your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with this question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I will look into Listeners as you suggest as I only just picked up Java programming. Thanks for your comments. Also just so that this get some closure, I posted the solution I found to this problem.

Comment: Yeah, and unfortunately it's not a good solution. Your question is a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type question where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: I understand, I will try to ask questions the proper way from now on.

Comment: In fact, I'd venture to say that this whole thing could be solved by your using a modal JDialog for the welcome screen window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reading @Hovercraft Full Of Eels's comment again I figured that the problem lied in my inheritance and he was right. I removed the `extends` from both my classes: `WelcomeScreen` and `Tutorial` and then made small methods to return values from one class to another while using a single instance for each class, like so:
In the `Startup` I did:

```
private WelcomeScreen welcomeScreen = new WelcomeScreen();
public boolean isDoneWelcoming(){
    System.out.print("Boolean \"doneWelcoming\" value returned as: "+doneWelcoming+br);
    return welcomeScreen.returnToStartup();
}
```

In `WelcomeScreen` I added:

```
private Tutorial startTutorial = new Tutorial();
boolean returnToStartup(){
    return startTutorial.returnToWelcome();
}
```

In `Tutorial` I added:

```
buttonClicked=false;
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            buttonClicked = true;
        }
});
//and as a separate boolean
boolean returnToWelcome() {
    while (!letsgoClicked) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ah this is a Swing program. I double down on my last comment that your busy while loop is bad. Don't do this. Use a listener such as a ChangeListener or PropertyChangeListener as doing so will allow you to code with the Swing library not against it.